Conditional Expected Stopping Time for Brownian Motion with Drift
I previously asked the following question: Expected stopping time for Brownian motion conditional on lower barrier being hit first.
I attempted to extend the result to a Brownian motion with drift, but was unable to do so, I tried working with the Girsanov transform, but couldn't make any progress. What is the expected stopping time in the following problem? (I've reposted the original text for convenience)
"Suppose we have a Brownian motion $B(t)$, with $B(0) = 0$, and boundaries $a < 0 < b$. Define $\tau_a = \min\{t : B(t) = a\}$ and $\tau_b = \min\{t : B(t) = b\}.$ Conditional on the fact that $a$ was hit first, what is the expected stopping time? I.e., what is $\mathbf{E}[\tau_a | \tau_a < \tau_b]?$
I wanted to use the optional stopping theorem, but it didn't fit, since $\mathbf{E}[B(\tau_a)] = a \neq \mathbf{E}[B(0)].$ Similarly, I couldn't figure out how to use the reflection principle to tackle the problem. I'm aware that without conditioning on the fact that $\tau_a < \tau_b$, the expected stopping time would be infinite, but I think it should be finite when the conditioning is included since it eventually must hit one of the two barriers."
I'm trying to solve the above problem, with the twist that now: $B(t) = \mu t + \sigma W_t$ where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion, and $\mu \neq 0$.
Thank you for your help!
